# In Java Swing, is there a way to save files to some sort of 'lib' folder?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Right now, I can save a file based on a word processor I made in Java Swing. When they press the save button, `JFileChooser` asks where they would like to save it to. I would like it so that every time the user saves, that a backup is generated in a `lib` folder, so that the user may revert back to a previous copy. Is there a way I can say generate a folder inside a `bin` folder for each respective file that the user has, and inside that folder generates the copies. For example, the user creates a file called `MyDoc.rtf` and inside `lib` generates a folder called `MyDoc` and inside has all the copies of the saved versions `copy1`, `copy2,`, `copy3`, etc.

So, there are two parts to the question. How do I generate a cache folder for each file saved? And how do I generate those copies?

The way I save the file using `JFileChooser` is as follows

```
public class SaveContent {
String formattedText;

public void save(JTextPane text){
    if(text.getText().length() > 0){
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("RICH TEXT FORMAT", "rtf", "rtf");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

        int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        if(!chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtf")){
            filePath=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath() + ".rtf";
        }

        if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)text.getDocument();
            HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
            BufferedOutputStream out;

            try{
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                kit.write(out,doc,doc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), doc.getLength());
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

            } catch(IOException e){

            } catch(BadLocationException e){

            }
        } else{
            System.out.println("SAVE CANCCELED");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Upon looking at other sources, I guess I can use ```.mkdirs()``` first to geneate a directory if it doesn't already exist. Within that, I can use ```JFileChooser``` and specify the relative path. i.e. ```.../backups/CoolDoc```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a directory that doesn't already exist, I can simply do `mkdirs()` and then use `Files` to write to a path. Alternatively, I can use `FileWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, and `FileOutputStream`.

```
          if(textListiner != null) {
                textListiner.textEmitted("GOodeye\n");

                //Add a folder
                File f = new File("../Swing1/backups/testDir");
                if(!f.exists()) {
                    boolean success = (new File("../Swing1/backups/testDir")).mkdirs();
                    if (!success) {
                        // Directory creation failed
                        System.out.println("FAIL CREATE DIR");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("ALREADY EXISTS");
                }               
            }

                //Add the file to the folder (without JFileChooser and showSaveDialog)
                // COuld use FileWriter, BufferedWriter FIleOutputStream, or Files
                //Lookup: https://www.journaldev.com/878/java-write-to-file
                String data;
                try {
                    Files.write(Paths.get("../Swing1/backups/testDir/copy1.txt"), data.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException eIO) {
                    eIO.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are suggesting to use the cumbersome old legacy Java File API instead of NIO?

Comment: @Zabuza to be honest, it's the first working solution I found. What's wrong with old legacy?

Comment: Multiple things. There is a reason this was completely replaced by NIO in Java 7. For example default encoding issues. Or correct error messages on failure. Or reading and writing files with just a single line of code.